# Controller.from_port is raising error

Tags: python, sockets, tor, stem

I am trying to get stem controller. I have started tor as `sudo /etc/init.d/tor start` which starts tor.

Now when in python I run, `controller = Controller.from_port()` it raises exception that `stem.SocketError:[Error 111] Connection refused`

I looked around and found that this exception is raised if tor is not running, but I have started tor. Then why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Please provide your torrc, most likely you either don't have a ControlPort or are connecting to the SocksPort instead. See the ['hello world' tutorial](https://stem.torproject.org/tutorials/the_little_relay_that_could.html) for help on getting initially set up.